# What components are involved in this kind of scroll?

Tags: paper, material-identification

I've seen pictures of scrolls such as this, that contain their material within a larger metal case, and are read by pulling the material out using a tab on the side.

[image: Skyrim: Elder Scroll]

<sup>Image from game: Skyrim</sup>

All of them, such as this one, are not actually real. It makes me curious as to whether or not these kinds of scrolls ever existed.

Supposing that this kind is real, what real life/ historical scrolls exist that are of this style? What are the basic parts that make up the scroll? I am not looking for complete design specifications but more of a basic schematic.
[image: DS3 Crystal Scroll]

<sup>Image from Dark Souls 3</sup>

Also I've found another picture, from dark souls 3, that is still fictional though it represents what I'm looking to identify.

Comment: This question is too broad after you discover these scrolls are real. It's a larger project and your answer would require a step-by-step tutorial, making it off-topic, which is why I'm closing. You could instead [edit] to try asking about the types of parts/pieces needed and if you get stuck assembling them ask a specific question about that step. We'll look at this question again after you edit to open it if needed.

Comment: It's an unusual configuration, but fancier megillah scrolls are designed like this. (That being said, I agree this is too broad as it currently stands!)

Comment: There are examples of such scrolls in museums. Actually they are used today. And the assembly is not complex. Sure, the one shown in the picture is quite ornate but that's just surface finish. The real question, I think, Naos is asking is to learn how something like this would be assembled. A straight forward crafts question ... isn't it?

Comment: @CreationEdge  I have edited it. I apologize for wording it in a way that made it too broad, and so I summarized to the best of my ability what I wanted to ask. Somehow I feel as though it is difficult to avoid being broad when you are uncertain if the object your asking about even exists, but perhaps that is just me, but hopefully you understand.

Comment: It's understandable. Being closed isn't a bad thing, because you can always edit to get things on track. No need to apologize. Welcome, and good luck.

Comment: I made some changes to question to at least focus on the scroll type/identification (which you have received an answer). Since you had nowhere to start at least seeing other scrolls will give you a starting point into their creation. If you are actually having issues with your build or design I would encourage you to ask more question here. How to make this questions are generally very broad and cannot be fully answered in this format. So, if you end of having specific issues or questions we welcome them.

Comment: I have heard of Megillahs, but they are a scroll with this type of format, not the type itself. Once someone has identified the style, I should be able to research it, or at least that was the plan.

Comment: Are you looking for a more specific term than "scroll in a case"?

Comment: @Erica that can refer to both the type and just a regular scroll in a case. A more specific term would help, if there is one.

Comment: Tangentially related, an [interesting blog post about modern perceptions of scrolls](https://foundinantiquity.com/2013/07/17/ancient-scrolls-where-are-the-wooden-handles/).

Answer (score 6):

These types of scrolls do exist.

One example is called an "Esther" scroll case.

Here are some examples.

http://www.museumsinisrael.gov.il/en/items/Pages/ItemCard.aspx?IdItem=ICMS_IMJ_366069

http://www.magnes.org/collections/museum/jewish-life/synagogue-and-communal-life/esther-scroll-collection

http://www.imj.org.il/imagine/galleries/viewWallE.asp?case=34&srm=Purim&swl=The%20Esther%20Scroll

And ... if I were to try to make something similar I would break it down to the following parts.

[image]

Comment: Interesting concept, only it doesn't answer the other part of the question, which is what it is.